# Выделение ячейки в JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Есть задание сделать что-то  вроде электронной таблицы. Обработчик выражений сделал, а вот с интерфейсом проблемы.

Проблема в следующем: мне нужно, чтобы можно было выделять только ячейку, без столбца и ряда.

Если использовать:

```
table.setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);
table.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
```

Тогда выделение происходит одной ячейки, но когда выбираю несколько, зажав Ctrl - выделяются несколько на одной линии, либо по диагонали.

Очень нужна подсказка, чтоб это решить.

Comment: По-моему, из коробки это не сделать, надо переопределять методы `JTable`. Посмотрите [этот ответ на SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15590775/5661663)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать

```
table.getColumnModel().setColumnSelectionAllowed( true );
```

Comment: реакция такая же.(

Comment: А если такое попробовать ?table.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);

Comment: такое делал в первую очередь !